# I am stuck on a particular trigonometry composite function

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

I know my composite function will be tan(x)+1/tan(x)-1, but I do not know how to move forward. I would greatly appreciate a hint please.
Thank you!

Comment: Replace tan(x) with sin(x)/cos(x)

Comment: There is trig identity for tan(x) + 1 which would also lead to further simplifications, also recall what 1 can be substituted as

Comment: @user78090 I found it! Thank you very much! But what about the domain?

Comment: To find domain, solve $\cos x \ne 0, \sin x \ne \cos  x$

Comment: Since they're being specific with the domains of the first two functions, you need to extend that specificity to the composite function.  The domain starts off the same as the inside function f(x) and then you'd need to exclude anything where you get a result from f(x) that's outside the domain of g(x).  So, if tan(x) can ever give an answer of 1 (the only thing excluded from g(x)) then you exclude that x from the domain also.

Comment: @Johnathan, I have noticed your last 3 questions history, You have put very low efforts into solving questions, Even posted 3 consecutive questions of trigonometry withing last 3 hours, Are you solving some exercise and just asking doubts wherever you seem to get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the composite function,here I have done only the next calculation.$$\frac{\tan x +1}{\tan x -1}=\frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+1}{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-1}=\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin x-\cos x}$$